# Simplify $\text{Tr}[(A-I)\Sigma_X(A-I)^\top+\Sigma_{\xi}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I encounter a problem as below: $$\mathcal{L}(A,\Sigma_{\xi})=\text{Tr}[(A-I)\Sigma_X(A-I)^\top+\Sigma_{\xi}].$$

One approach I'm trying is to replace $(A, \Sigma_{\xi})$ with $(\tilde A, I)$ with $\tilde A=\sqrt{D^{-1}}VA$ and $\Sigma_{\xi}=VDV^\top$ so that the number of variables to be optimized could be reduced. I want to see whether such a replacement would change the value of the objective function:

\begin{align}
&\text{Tr}[(\tilde A-I)\Sigma_X(\tilde A -I)+I]\\
=&\text{Tr}[\sqrt{D^{-1}}VA\Sigma_XA^\top V^\top\sqrt{D^{-T}}-\sqrt{D^{-1}}VA\Sigma_X-\Sigma_XA^\top V^\top\sqrt{D^{-T}}+\Sigma_X+I]\\
=&\text{Tr}[\sqrt{D^{-1}}V(A\Sigma_XA^\top-A\Sigma_X\sqrt{D^{T}}V-V^\top\sqrt{D}\Sigma_XA^\top +V^\top\sqrt{D}\Sigma_X\sqrt{D^{T}}V+\Sigma_{\xi})V^\top\sqrt{D^{-T}}]\\
=&\text{Tr}[\sqrt{D^{-1}}V((A-V^\top\sqrt{D})\Sigma_X(A-V^\top\sqrt{D})^\top+\Sigma_{\xi})V^\top\sqrt{D^{-T}}].
\end{align}
Is there any way to further simplify the equations? Thanks!

Comment: What is there to prevent $\operatorname{Tr}\Sigma_\xi$ from becoming arbitrarily large, for example?

Comment: Are there any constraints on $A$ and $\Sigma_{\xi}$? Either letting $\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_{\xi})\to\infty$ or $A=xI$ with $x\to\infty$ (assuming $\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_X)>0$ in the latter case) makes $\mathcal{L}$ grow unboundedly.

Comment: @user10354138 and Sangchul Lee, sorry for passing the wrong message, I made a stupid mistake in the optimization part, please ignore it. If you have any idea on how to simplify the equation, welcome to discuss. Thanks a lot!